# passing data from javascript using ajax and saving it to a database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Hi guys I currently have a website that lets users search a website, I would like to save these search terms and the amount of times each has been searched in a database. To this end I have created a table with 2 columns search which is varchar(30) and value which is int(30) search is set to unique so that terms for instance design don't populate two rows however when i run the program nothing is being saved to the database i was wondering if any of you could help.

javascript

```
function performSearch() {
    var searchURL = "http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/soc/search?q=";
    var searchTerms = $('#searchterm').val();
    var searchReady = searchTerms.toLowerCase();
    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'findfavourites.php',
                    data: {searchReady : searchReady},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert("success!");
                    }
                });
    $('#soctable tbody').empty();
    $.getJSON(searchURL + searchReady, function(results) {
        results.forEach(function (result) {
        var row = $("<tr></tr>");
        var codeCell = $("<td></td>");
        var titleCell = $("<td></td>");
        var descriptionCell = $("<td></td>");
        var qualificationsCell = $("<td></td>");
        var tasksCell = $("<td></td>");
        codeCell.html(result.soc);
        titleCell.html(result.title);
        descriptionCell.html(result.description);
        qualificationsCell.html(result.qualifications);
        tasksCell.html(result.tasks);
        row.append(codeCell);
        row.append(titleCell);
        row.append(descriptionCell);
        row.append(qualificationsCell);
        row.append(tasksCell);
        $('#soctable tbody').append(row);
    });
   });

}


$(function() {
    // when the page is loaded
    $('#dosearch').on('click', performSearch);
});
```

PHP

```
<?php

    include 'includes/dbConnection.php';
    if(isset($_POST['searchReady']))
    {
          $uid = $_POST['searchReady'];
      $value='1';
    $query=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO favourites VALUES        ('$uid','$value') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value + 1");
    $query->execute();
    $conn = null;
}   
?>
```

any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

*edit*

@PHPglue

im sure you were asking for the page the getjson returns results to if so here is the html page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1">
<title>Homepage</title>
<link href="styleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="soc.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="page">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Careers and Apprenticeships</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<header>
  <h1><u>Careers and Apprenticeships</u></h1>
</header>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<input class="form control" type="text" id="searchterm" placeholder="Put your search term here...">
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="dosearch">Search!</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<table class="table table-striped" id="soctable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>SOC Code</th>
<th>Job Title</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Qualifications</th>
<th>Tasks</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

*EDIT 2*

Hi everyone I have discovered that the ajax is working and the problem is cause by the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE could any one perhaps check the syntax and tell me if you see any problems. As I said above I would like this value to update to 2 when the same term is searched and so on.

Comment: AJAX calls that are dependent on other AJAX calls, must be nested within the dependent AJAX.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by this could you explain?

Comment: Have you checked the output of $uid? Is that making it to the server?

Comment: Just a comment. I don't see you using `data` anyways. Not sure why you want 2 AJAX queries, that's all. Where's your `$.getJSON(searchURL + searchReady` page? That PHP only works `if(isset($_POST['searchReady']))`.

Comment: everything seems fine apart from line 21 of the php file throwing error "PDOStatement->execute()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\practiceapi\\findfavourites.php on line 21,

Comment: @PHPglue hi again i am no where near an expert with ajax honestly this is my first time using it are you saying I would be better just sending search terms to the php file from within the getjson ajax queries and if so could you perhaps show me an example of how to perform this thanks

Comment: Hi everyone I have discovered that the ajax is working and the problem is cause by the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE could any one perhaps check the syntax and tell me if you see any problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try amending the sql line to:

```
$query=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO favourites 
  VALUES ('$uid','$value') 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = value + 1");
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Great to hear @Bob